# Create Content Manager for JSF 2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I want to develop an Web Application, and I want to build a Content Manager.
I have 3 web applications, each in different EARs and all application are deployed in the same Web Application Server (WebSphere). I want to build a principal application(Content Manager) with a menu and this application should call and show the others applications for example:

```
   --------Main Application JSF --------------------------------------
    ---Menu -> Application 1 (URL remote JSF Application) (clic in this)
               Application 2 (URL remote JSF Application)
               Application 3 (URL remote JSF Application)

   ------- Dynamic content into Main Application JSF--------

     // Hear load the external JSF Application (Application 1)  
     // if clic Application 2 in the menu, load de Application 2
     // and the Application 1 is hidden or unload.

   ------- Dynamic content into Main Application JSF--------
```

My question is, I need some ideas to how to develop a Main Application JSF, I prefer don't use iframe if is possible.

Comment: Why don't you try to put a link from application 1 to application 2 and application 1 from application 2 and the same for the other. Because doing a Main application will slow down the other application.

Comment: maybe it's a good idea, but when I needing create an other application (application 6 for example), the new application should include the menu, in others words, each new application should include the same menu, and my idea is have a only one main application JSF with two parts, one the menu in the top and the second the dynamic content below of menu.